# JSON not parsing - TypeError

Tags: javascript, json

I have to following sample JSON:

```
{
 "findItemsByKeywordsResponse":[
  {
     "ack":[
        "Success"
     ],
     "version":[
        "1.13.0"
     ],
     "timestamp":[
        "2015-02-10T18:12:21.785Z"
     ],
     "searchResult":[
        {
           "@count":"100",
           "item":[
              {
                 "itemId":[
                    "371250980931"
                 ],
                 "title":[ etc etc...
```

I'm trying to parse it as follows:

```
function _cb_findItemsByKeywords(root) {
  var items = root.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];
  etc etc...
}
```

But get the following error:

```
TypeError: root.findItemsByKeywordsResponse is undefined
    var items = root.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];
    ----^
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is not about parsing but accessing presumably parsed element.

Comment: Yes thats correct, parsing is the nearest description I could think of

Comment: Just an idea: Did you check your root variable's content: `alert(JSON.stringify(root))`? This may show you're working with a different json that you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the root

```
function _cb_findItemsByKeywords(root) {
  root = JSON.parse(root);
  var items = root.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];
  etc etc...
}
```

A JSON is only a String to Javascript and you need to parse it to an Object.